# Finding an average from several years of data

Tags: mysql

I would like to create a function, rather than a usual query.

I want to do a SUM of all daily figures for a given month, doing this for each instance of that given month from several years of data. I would like to find an AVG figure for those totals if I can.

The bit that I'm finding particularly tricky is that I've stored the dates as `YYYY-MM-DD`. So the function needs to total dailies of a given month and do so for each year in the dataset.

Any assistance would be so helpful.

p.s. just to add all the relevant data, the date and the figures, are in one table called 'PurchaseHistory'.

Sample info as requested:

```
DateOfPayment   Amount
2017-01-10      10.15
2017-01-10      10.15 
2017-01-11      10.15 
2017-01-12      20.15 
2017-01-15      10.15 
2017-01-15      10.15 
2017-01-18      20.10 
2017-01-18      20.05 
2017-02-15      15.89 
2017-02-17      10.15 
2017-02-17      15.89 
2017-02-17      10.15
```

And so on, but for each month going back to 2016.

So far I have:

```
SELECT YEAR(DateOfPayment), MONTH(DateOfPayment), SUM(Amount)
FROM DateOfPayment
GROUP BY YEAR(DateOfPayment), MONTH(DateOfPayment)
```

This gets me the totals per month for each year. But now I need to find the average for a specific month and add a parameter so it can be specified. But I will happily settle for a list of averages for each month from across the years.

Comment: it will be great if you provide some table information and sample input output.

Comment: Hi OP, it is impossible for us to help you write code if you don't know your field names, what your data looks like in the DB, and what you want it to look like. Even 5 test rows helps :)

Comment: hey guys, I'm just put in some sample content from the tables - you are quite right to ask, my bad! :)

Comment: I advice you to [read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) this when providing example data and expected results.

Comment: oops formatting was bad - corrected

Comment: This format we can't use to easy make a test case..We will be copying all this information..

Comment: But most likely you can try the query  `SELECT YEAR(DateOfPayment), MONTH(DateOfPayment), AVG(Amount) FROM table GROUP BY YEAR(DateOfPayment), MONTH(DateOfPayment)`

Comment: oh, i see what you mean. I will have a go at doing it again

Comment: Best publish what you tried that way we won't provide an answer which is known not to work for you , and expected result based on your sample data would also help.

Comment: That's a very interesting reply Raymond. I like how you've pulled out the month and the year there! I just need to get this as a function; I would like to have a parameter to set the month, as I don't want to see all results - just maybe the month of June for example or July on another occasion. Does that make sense? I also want the average, to be the average of all the totals for that month, rather than on any particular month.

Comment: Thank you P.Salmon I will add something now. Raymonds answer is very helpful. I just need it as a function, and want the averages for all the totals of say the month of June - rather than the average on June 2015

Comment: " don't want to see all results - just maybe the month of June for example "...so you just need a where clause with a parameter. "want the average, to be the average of all the totals for that month"...this might require an outer query wrapping round the results of the first query

Comment: Yes ADyson that's what I was wondering. If for example the SUM totals of June 2015 was 1500, the SUM total of June 2016 was 1800, the SUM total of June 2017 was 1200 ... then I would want the average of those figues

Comment: This question seems to be evolving , it's at the point where I am unsure what you want . Perhaps you want to pass a date range and average over the sums for each month within the range?

Comment: Sorry perhaps I'm not super at explaining things. All I want is to total the figures for each month. Look at all those totals, for say the month of June 2016-2018. Then see what the average is. I would like to have a parameter to set what the month is. Does that help?

Comment: It seems to be you need something like the materialized view in Oracle, unfortunately, this feature is not in MySQL, I don't like to put a random link here but if you google "materialised view alternative in mysql" that will bring some useful link to look at

Comment: I added some code in the main entry - also thank you for that suggestion justMe :) I'll take a peak!

Answer (score 0):

If i did understand, what you need is sum the Amounts for every day and then get the average for every month, so you could get the dayly sum in the inner query and then get the monthly average in the outer query:

```
SELECT YEAR(b.DateOfPayment),MONTH(b.DateOfPayment),AVG(b.TotalDay)
FROM
    (SELECT a.DateOfPayment, SUM(a.Amount) as TotalDay
    FROM DateOfPayment a
    GROUP BY a.DateOfPayment) 
GROUP BY YEAR(b.DateOfPayment),MONTH(b.DateOfPayment)
```

**EDIT**

Fix a bug:

```
SELECT YEAR(b.DateOfPayment),MONTH(b.DateOfPayment),AVG(b.TotalDay)
FROM
    (SELECT a.DateOfPayment, SUM(a.Amount) as TotalDay
    FROM DateOfPayment a
    GROUP BY a.DateOfPayment) b
GROUP BY YEAR(b.DateOfPayment),MONTH(b.DateOfPayment)
```

Comment: yeah i coudn't get this one to work, I see what you were doing with the a and b and adjusted mine to do the same, but it just says 'every derived table needs an alias'

Comment: Sorry, there is a small mistake, i make a change to fix it